# How to get image using Onenote api?

Tags: onenote

I am using onenote api for display the page. Page contents are displaying properly. But I got images broken link.

I have added another get option for get the images. But I got Odata Notsupport    or Method Not allowed error message.

Please advise how to get the image form onenote pages?

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote API requires all of its API calls to be secured by an OAUTH bearer token.  So you can't just push the content of the HTML from the API into a browser, because the image references won't get the auth passed on by the browser.

I've created a uservoice issue [here](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-apis/suggestions/7916235-ability-to-get-pre-auth-d-image-urls-from-a-onenot) for you to vote on to request this feature.

In the meantime, you'll need to write your own code to GET from these image URLs with the same auth token that you used to get the page HTML initially, then swap the URLs out to point to wherever you choose to store those resources.